# CodeDom CompilerVersion issue

Tags: c#

I'm using CodeDom to compile my source. And I'm trying to set the target framework like that:

```
            Dictionary<string, string> providerOptions = new Dictionary<string, string>() { { "CompilerVersion", "v4.0" } };

CodeDomProvider objCodeCompiler = new Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.CSharpCodeProvider(providerOptions)
```

But that doesn't work, I get following error:
[error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D8ATf.png)

I tried to selcect the CompilerVersion in app.config but that doesn't work aswell:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
<startup><supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.8"/></startup>
<appSettings>
<add key="aspnet:RoslynCompilerLocation" value="roslyn"/>
</appSettings>
  <system.codedom>
    <compilers>
      <!-- zero or more compiler elements -->
      <compiler
        language="c#;cs;csharp"
        extension=".cs"
        type="Microsoft.CSharp.CSharpCodeProvider, System,   
          Version=2.0.1.0, Culture=neutral,   
          PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089"
        compilerOptions="/optimize"
        warningLevel="4" >
        <providerOption
          name="CompilerVersion"
          value="v4.6" />
      </compiler>
    </compilers>
  </system.codedom>
</configuration>
```

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

My guess is you are probably reading the API for this (update to your appropriate .NET version):

> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.csharp.csharpcodeprovider.

However, the package you are using is likely this one:

> https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform

In short, the CSharpCodeProvider (and backend compiler) is different. I'm not sure if there are API docs for this but the source is here:

> https://github.com/aspnet/RoslynCodeDomProvider/blob/a47558d50056fed7b745cfdfebc392e0e82e1b8d/src/Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform/CSharpCodeProvider.cs

In addition, specifying the CompilerVersion appears to be N/A as per line 27 here:

> https://github.com/aspnet/RoslynCodeDomProvider/blob/master/src/Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform/Util/IProviderOptions.cs

I suppose your resolution is either to use the Microsoft.CSharp.CSharpCodeProvider (ie `new new Microsoft.CodeDom.CSharpCodeProvider(providerOptions)`) or use the Roslyn one and adhere to the API. I guess the latter is probably most appropriate but ultimately this depends on the nuances of your situation.